# What does "deliver to" mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

According to Oxford Dictionary, the verb *deliver* means:

> Bring and hand over (a letter, parcel, or goods) to the proper recipient or address.

How does adding the preposition *to* change this meaning?

Comment: Can you please provide an example sentence.

Comment: "Part of the growth is related to the consolidation of the JV with Magnetti Marelli FCA in Pernambuco, delivering to FCA, which has a good profitability and good activity."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, "to" does not change the meaning. You could say, "I delivered the mail to the house", "I will deliver this later", or "Have you delivered the parcel to her house?"...they all work. "To" is simply used to show where the delivery is going. So, if you aren't specifying where you are delivering something, you could just say "I will deliver it". If you were specifying the place, you could say, "I will deliver it to the house". (Excuse any grammar mistakes I may have made!)